# creating a dynamic sidebar with zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to create a dynamic sidebar in zend framework. I have googled some articles, browsed even the stackoverflow archive but i can't seem to get it so please help me figure this out.
    Here is some code from my layout.phtml file:

```
<div id="contentWrapper">
<div id="contentArea">
<?php echo $this->layout()->content;
?>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="user-authentication">
        <?php if (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) {
        ?>Logged In as<br />
        <?php
            echo Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();
        } else {
        ?>

            <input type="text" name="login" class="loginInput" /><br/>    
            <input type="password" name="password" class="loginInput" /><br/>    

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" class="loginButton" />    
<?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar-content">
                            <? echo $this->layout()->sidebar; ?>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

I could use this [Best practice creating dynamic sidebar with zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421013/best-practice-creating-dynamic-sidebar-with-zend-framework) but that means I would need to have redundant code for displaying the login box/logged in as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just worried about the repetition of hasIdentity and getIdentity in the sidebar-content div?

If so, maybe you'd prefer this:

```
<?php
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $user = $auth->hasIdentity() ? $auth->getIdentity : NULL;
?>
<div id="user-authentication">
    <?php if ($user) { ?>
        User stuff.
    <?php } else { ?>
        Public stuff.
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<div id="user-authentication">
    <?php if ($user) { ?>
        User stuff.
    <?php } else { ?>
        Public stuff.
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

However, that's just a matter of coding style. There's nothing wrong with checking a users logged in state more than once. It's necessary with modular code to do so; that's probably why Zend_Auth is a Singleton.

Comment: i have managed to do with using partials. It gives. I have my login as a partial and other sidebar parts as partials and I love the fact that it gives me the flexibility of loading which partial i want wherever i want. In my layout i only have $this->layout()->content. In my view files i am loading the partials. Works well so far and it's very flexible. I am going to approve your answer because it has helped me thinking of this (although i have read some other articles about it i was skeptical)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a widget:

- [Using Action Helpers To Implement Re-Usable Widgets - phly, boy, phly](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/246-Using-Action-Helpers-To-Implement-Re-Usable-Widgets.html)

For displaying or not some of the content, look for integration of `Zend_Acl` and `Zend_Navigation`.
It is as easy as: `$container->setAcl($acl)`